# Basic Set Theory: Cardinality of Union of index sets is equal to the cardinality of each index set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I think that this problem utilizes a surjection $\mathit{f}$ : $\mathit{A} \to \mathit{A_n}$, which implies that $\omicron{(A)} \ge \omicron{\mathit{( A_n)}}$, and the fact that $\cup{}_{\mathit{n} \in \mathbb{N}}A_\mathit{n}$ is equinumerous to the cartesian product $\mathit{A} \times \mathbb{N}$, but I cannot figure out how to synthesize these pieces into a cohesive answer.

For each $\mathit{n} \in \mathbb{N}$ let $A_\mathit{n}$ be a set such that $\omicron{(A_\mathit{n})}=\mathit{d}$, an infinite cardinal number.

Prove: $\omicron{(\cup{}_{\mathit{n} \in \mathbb{N}}A_\mathit{n})}=\mathit{d}.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n$, and for each $a\in A$ let $n(a)=\min\{k\in\Bbb N:a\in A_k\}$. For each $n\in\Bbb N$ there is a bijection $f_n:A_n\to A_0$. Let

$$F:A\to A_0\times\Bbb N:a\mapsto\langle f_{n(a)}(a),n(a)\rangle\;;$$

you can easily verify that $F$ is an injection, so $o(A)\le o(A_0\times\Bbb N)=d$. On the other hand, there is an obvious injection from $A_0$ into $A$, do $d=o(A_0)\le o(A)$, and it follows that $o(A)=d$.

Comment: This is very helpful - could you comment on how we define a function from union of index sets to the cartesian product of A and the natural numbers? Defining such a function still perplexes me.

Comment: @Koryf: The displayed line actually gives the definition of the function: for each $a\in A$ we first fine $n(a)$, the smallest index of any $A_k$ containing $a$, and then we send $a$ to $\langle f_{n(a)}(a),n(a)\rangle$. Here $f_{n(a)}$ is the element of $A_0$ corresponding to $a\in A_{n(a)}$ via the bijection $f_{n(a)}:A_{n(a)}\to A_0$. (Recall that all of the sets $A_k$ have the same cardinality, $d$, so for simplicity I just use $A_0$ as a stand-in for all of them, so that I have a single set of cardinality $d$ whose Cartesian product I take with $\Bbb N$. The pair ...

Comment: ... $\langle f_{n(a)},n(a)\rangle$ uniquely identifies $a$: the second component identifies an $A_k$ that contains $a$, and applying $f_{n(a)}$ to the first component then recovers $a$ itself.